# Getting syntax error for sqlsrv_query

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sqlsrv

I am new to `SQL`. For my `PHP` application I am using HTML, PHP and SQL
Below code for add the insert query.

```
$insert_query = "INSERT INTO policy_request (user_name, user_mobile, user_email, user_car_model, user_policy_expiry_date, request_from, policy_created_on) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$params = array('".$user_name."', $user_mobile, '".$user_email."', '".$user_car_model."', '".$policy_date."', '".$request_url."', '".$created_on."');
if(!sqlsrv_query($conn,$insert_query,$params)){
    //echo "inside";exit; 
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors())); exit;
}else{
    echo "rows inserted";
    exit;
}
```

I am getting error like this

```
 [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => IMSSP
        [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP
        [1] => -14
        [code] => -14
        [2] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query.
        [message] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query.
    )
```

I dont know where I made mistake.
FYI db connection established.

Comment: In addition to my answer, are you 100% sure your connection to the DB is correct. An error with the SQLSTATE in IMSSP and a code of -14 seems to suggest that a connection could not be made. *"the plain meaning of SQLSTATE "IMSSP", CODE "-14" is that you provided no valid connection object to your sqlsrv_query function."* [user note from php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php#Hcom112287)

Answer (score 0):

By the look of your parameters array, you appear to be trying to pass the parameters as one long string, with the values separated by commas. This is incorrect.

Firstly, your attempt to do so is incorrect. You have a few missing quotes - missing first and last `"` in the string, and missing quotes and concatenation around `$user_mobile`.

Secondly, you are only sending one parameter (the string), when the query is expecting seven.

`$params` should be an array with the same amount of values as you have placeholders (`?`) in your query. In this case you have seven placeholders, therefore you should have seven values in the `$params` array. Like so:

```
$params = array($user_name, $user_mobile, $user_email, $user_car_model, $policy_date, $request_url, $created_on);
```

Comment: Hi clarky.
i changed as per you said. i have 12 fields . i include the 12 values also but its show the same error
$insert_query = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[policy_request]
           ([policy_unique_id]  ,[user_name] ,[user_mobile],[user_email],[user_car_model] ,[request_from] ,[user_policy_expiry_date],[policy_created_on],[age],[earnings],[otp],[otp_status]) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";$params = array(3,$user_name, $user_mobile, $user_email, $user_car_model,$request_url, $policy_date,$created_on,0,0,0,0);

Comment: @vigneshr - have you read my [other comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41583309/getting-syntax-error-for-sqlsrv-query/41587350?noredirect=1#comment70379328_41583309) (on the question) ?